# How to execute this @query variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(200);

SET @QUERY='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUD';
```

I have used this:

```
EXEC (@QUERY)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @QUERY
```

but it's not working.

```
ERROR: Must declare a scalar variable.
```

how to declare a scalar variable and how to execute this query.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: retagged with `sql-server` and `tsql` because of `EXECUTE sp_executesql`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 Declare @query nvarchar(max)
    Set @query = 'Select count(*) from stud'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following, as you can not execute the string in SSMS directly, You are required to put it in a Temp/Hash table as per your requirement.

**DECLARE** @QUERY VARCHAR(200);
**Declare** @tempTabl Table(countval int)

SET @QUERY='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Blogs';

Insert into @tempTabl

exec (@query)

select * from @tempTabl